# Vite developement server behind HAPROXY

Tags: typescript, vite, haproxy, monorepo

I'm working on a Typescript monorepo using NX that holds multiple services (CRA / hapi). All of these services are dockerised and served in their own port.
To bundle them all as a single app, we added an HAPROXY that serves each container behind a route.
I try to replace my old CRA with a new shiny Vite app. The problem is that the app I'm trying to convert has many routes that redirected to the CRA app.
The index.html was served using /collaborator and /manager and the ressources (static, bundle.js etc) served via /public and /p-app.

Haproxy conf:

```
frontend http-in
  bind *:80
  
  # many many things
  use_backend portal_app if { path_beg -i /manager/ }
  use_backend portal_app if { path_beg -i /collaborator/ }
  use_backend portal_app if { path_beg -i /public/ }
  use_backend portal_app if { path_beg -i /p-app/ }

backend portal_app
  server server1 myDockerImage:3001 check inter 1000 resolvers dockerdns resolve-prefer ipv4
```

The conf CRA was quite simple (and anyway not that configurable anyway), using a %PUBLIC_URL% env variable to prefix all resources in the index.html.
The main issue is when I switched to Vite:

- If i use the /p-app/ as the base path in Vite conf and navigate to `/collaborator/` or `/manager/` as I did before. I have errors like this:
  `The server is configured with a public base URL of /p-app/ - did you mean to visit /p-app/collaborator/ instead?`
- If I don't, there a problem resolving `<script type="module" src="/src/index.tsx"></script>` and `<script type="module" src="/@vite/client"></script>`

I'm kinda blocked, I sadly expected that migrating from the standard CRA to a standard Vite conf would be simpler. Do you have any insights on this ?

Thanks !